# python doctest check for a specific line

Tags: python, doctest

I'd like to write a doctest like this:

```
"""
>>> checking()
some random text
some more random text
...
test is passed ##ignore all above/below lines except this one 
more and more randomness
...
finished.
"""
```

I don't really care about first few lines or last few lines . I'm worried only about statement like "test is passed" . I tried something like

```
"""
>>> checking()
some random text
...
test is passed
...
finished.

"""
```

without success. Is this possible with doctest? Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [`ELLIPSIS`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/doctest.html#doctest.ELLIPSIS) flag:

```
>>> def checking():
...     """
...     >>> checking()  #doctest: +ELLIPSIS
...     header
...     ...
...     test is passed
...     ...
...     footer
...     """
...     print("header\nrandom\nlines\ntest is passed\nother\nrandom lines\nfooter")
>>> doctest.testmod(verbose=True)
Trying:
    checking()  #doctest: +ELLIPSIS
Expecting:
    header
    ...
    test is passed
    ...
    footer
ok
1 items had no tests:
    __main__
1 items passed all tests:
   1 tests in __main__.checking
1 tests in 2 items.
1 passed and 0 failed.
Test passed.
TestResults(failed=0, attempted=1)
```

The `...` can be used only in exception tracebacks without the `ELLIPSIS` option.

If you don't want to use the directives in the docstrings you can pass the `optionflags` parameter to the `doctest` functions:

```
>>> checking.__doc__ = ''.join(checking.__doc__.split('#doctest: +ELLIPSIS'))
>>> print checking.__doc__

    >>> checking()  
    header
    ...
    test is passed
    ...
    footer

>>> doctest.testmod(optionflags=doctest.ELLIPSIS)
TestResults(failed=0, attempted=2)
```